# Environment.Exit takes long time to close the application

Tags: c#, environment

I am trying to fix an issue that it is not clear to me.
When calling to `Environment.Exit(0)`, it takes about 22 sec to close the application.

```
if (AppDomain.CurrentDomain.IsDefaultAppDomain())
{
    Environment.Exit(exitCode);
}
```

Have you got any idea what is happening behind the scene?
I though maybe an exception is thrown but I checked all the checkboxes in Exceptions dialog.

Comment: I see your bug - you're using `Environment.Exit`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What's happening behind the scenes is quite clear if you understand how .NET applications work, and how `Environment.Exit` works.

In short, `Environment.Exit` is not the fastest way to exit an arbitrary application. It still waits for any pending finalizers to run (if they run fast enough, they only have 30 seconds total IIRC). If you're using e.g. sockets, it's perfectly possible that the finalizers take a few seconds to run.

The easiest way to check is of course to use the debugger - just Pause when doing the shutdown, and you'll see which threads are actually executing, and what it is they are executing.

Comment: Thank you, I can see lot of threads. Is there any command to exit without waiting the threads to end?

Comment: @ehh Yes, there's a few ways to do that. But you really don't want to - in fact, you shouldn't even use `Environment.Exit`. Just make sure all your threads finish cleanly and safely, and then exit as usual (e.g. `return;` in your `Main` method, or closing the main form of a windows form application).

Comment: I am clear that threads should finish cleanly and safely but why Environment.Exit should not be used?

Comment: @ehh Well, as soon as you have all the threads properly shutdown and everything, there isn't really a *reason* to use `Environment.Exit`. You can just as well do a `return` from Main, or close the main form of a winforms application, as noted before, and the whole application will close - and if it doesn't, you've just found a bug in your thread shutdown :) `Environment.Exit` has a nasty way of hiding errors like that - and it will easily kill your threads even in the middle of a `finally` statement, for example. It's inherently unsafe - it breaks a lot of the contract between you and .NET.